# Houdini versus the chess masters

Tags: logical-deduction, lateral-thinking, chess

As we all know, Houdini is very good at coming out on top against improbable odds! And oh boy are the odds improbable. For his next great performance, he claims he can play simultaneous chess games against the 8 best chess players in the world. Although he is a very smart man in other ways, he is a mediocre chess player at best.

8 chess tables are set in the room, and Houdini gets to play the white pieces in half the games. For this event, he scores 0 points for every loss, 1 point for every draw and 2 points for every win. He makes the ambitious claim:

*I will score no less than 8 points*

After all the games have been played, Houdini has scored, in fact, exactly 8 points. How did he do it?

Comment: Is this a trick question?

Comment: obviously there is a "trick" involved, but I wouldn't call it a trick question. there is no crazy nonsense in the answer, no play on words or such shenanigans.

Comment: Can you clarify "the white pieces in half the games"?

Comment: he plays a total of 8 simultaneous games. he plays the white pieces in 4 games and he plays the black pieces in 4 games. the white player always moves first.

Comment: I assume you took this puzzle from this popular video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=evZmpsl3jI0

Comment: Aside: [Houdini](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Houdini_%28chess%29) is actually one of the strongest chess engines in the world.

Comment: @imallett That's what I thought the answer was, before I saw the posted one.

Comment: @imallett you are absolutely right! who knows, maybe they named the chess computer after this riddle?

Comment: @BlueRaja-DannyPflughoeft no I heard it at school many years ago

Comment: [YouTube video of Derren Brown pulling this old trick](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wgk654mV-9g)

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Houdini cleverly paired up each game in which he played black with a game in which he played white. He then simply copied the moves played by his opponent to the corresponding game.

Comment: +1. Just a note that Houdini also has to make sure that he saw the grandmasters' who play white moves first before playing his own white moves.

Comment: It wouldn't work in reality, in real simultaneous chess he must make a move at the first board before he's allowed to move to the next, and his opponents only have to make their move when he shows up at their board.

Comment: How does this guarantee that he scores exactly eight points?

Comment: @FreeAsInBeer, it's guaranteed because Houdini wins a game if and only if he loses its paired game, so he scores 0 + 2 = 2 points. The same goes for draws (he scores 1 + 1 = 2 points). Since there are 4 game-pairs, he will always score exactly 8 points.

Comment: @Bret Thanks for the explanation, but I'm still not seeing why he *must* lose one of the paired games to win the other game against a different player.

Comment: @FreeAsInBeer He plays white in one game and black in the other, and the moves are exactly the same in both games.

Comment: @Bret But wouldn't his opponent's moves differ?

Comment: The key is that Houdini's "opponents" are essentially playing against each other. The two opponent's moves are different, but that is because they are playing different colors.

Comment: @FreeAsInBeer Let's say he's playing White on board A and Black on board B. By copying all the black moves from board A (his opponent's) as using them as his moves on board B - and vice versa for the white moves - he's basically letting his opponents play each other. It's like chess by mail except that Houdini is transcribing the moves instead of them being written down.

Comment: Ah, I see now. So he's guaranteed 8 points, but never more or less. That makes sense.

Comment: How does he decide his opening on the first board(s) he plays?

Comment: @KSmarts In order for this trick to work he has to play black first.

Comment: This riddle has just been stolen from Derren Brown https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rIAXIubSTkc

Answer (score -4):

He could have won 4 games and lost 4 (4x2 + 4x0 = 8), or drew all 8 (8x1 = 8).

Is there more to the question? I feel like I'm missing something..

Comment: this is not solving the puzzle at all! you missed the question. simultaneous chess in incredibly hard. How did Houdini managed to not get crushed in all 8 games? how did he score a single point? how did he score 8?

Comment: I think it was still a valid answer, even if it's not the right one - before the edit there was nothing to suggest that he'd be expected to lose.

Comment: :( Should I delete my answer? The question asked how 8 points were scored, and with the original wording I couldn't see why getting this score should be hard.

Comment: @Vajura I think this stackexchange is about having a friendly community to work on creating and solving puzzles, which to me would include showing how I interpret a puzzle I haven't come across before to help the creator refine their wording.

Comment: @ladyofcats If you have a question about the puzzle or feel it could be clarified, the appropriate place to do so is in the question comments. Answers are only for answering the question.